# Discord.py cannot synce

Tags: python, discord

**Task:**
I made this command that should create a file `.txt` file and if it has a valid name and it does not exist in `ListPython.txt`. But when I run it I get the error bellow. Could someone please help me?

**Code:**

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="newpython")
@app_commands.describe(FileName='FileName')
async def newpython(interaction: discord.Interaction,FileName: str):
    AddToLog(f'[INFO][{GetTime()}] newpython command has been used')
    _ = open("Program Files/ListPython.txt", "r")
    _ = _.read()
    _ = _.split()
    if FileName not in _:
        with open("Program Files/ListPython.txt", "a") as file1:
            file1.write(f' {FileName}')
            try:
                f = open(f"Python Files/{FileName}.txt", "x")
                await interaction.response.send_message(f"{FileName} created")
            except OSError:
                await interaction.response.send_message(f"{FileName} is a invalid file name.")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{FileName} already exists.")
```

**Error:**

```
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandSignatureMismatch: The signature for command 'newpython' is different from the one provided by Discord. This can happen because either your code is out of date or you have not synced the commands with Discord, causing the mismatch in data. It is recommended to sync the command tree to fix this issue.
```

> The problem is not for `app_commands` because when I removed it I still got the error though I could be wrong because I'm new to `discod.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with replacing:

```
@app_commands.describe(FileName='FileName')
```

with

```
@app_commands.describe(user='FileName')
```

I really don't know how this fix the problem but it does